# cannot retrieve android properties using ./gradlew properties command

Tags: android, gradlew

I am trying to retrieve the Android.compileSdkVersion property in my Android project using the command line "./gradlew properties".

However, I am unable to do so. But retrieved some other properties, like sourceCompatibility，properties: {...}.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 33
        applicationId rootProject.ext.android.applicationId
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.android.minSdkVersion
```

Here is some output when I run ./gradlew -q app:properties:

```
allprojects: [project ':app']
android: extension 'android'
android.nonTransitiveRClass: true
android.useAndroidX: true
androidComponents: extension 'androidComponents'
...
sourceCompatibility: 13
sourceSets: SourceSet container
standardOutputCapture: org.gradle.internal.logging.services.DefaultLoggingManager@1aac2762
state: project state 'EXECUTED'
status: integration
subprojects: []
targetCompatibility: 13
...
projectPath: :app
properties: {...}
taskThatOwnsThisObject: null
version: unspecified
zipStoreBase: GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath: wrapper/dists
```

As you can see, I can retrieve the `targetCompatibility` value and not the `compileSdkVersion` value. I have tried updating my Gradle version, clearing the Gradle cache, and running the `./gradlew properties` command in the correct project directory, but I am still unable to retrieve the `compileSdkVersion` value.

my Gradle version is 8.2-milestone-1. I have downloaded the appropriate SDK version and my project structure is correctly set up. I have also searched for similar issues on Stack Overflow, but I have not found any helpful solutions.

Can anyone provide a solution to help me retrieve the `compileSdkVersion` value by command line? Thank you!